# Java Regex Matching Classes inside Classes

Tags: java, regex, class

Hey so I already searched the internet for various examples but I cannot get to work the following Regex. I am trying to remove every char out of a String list entry that doesn't match my pattern.

My pattern looks like this for example:
e2-e4, d4-d5 and occasionally a specific last char may be given.

First of every line gets filtered with the following pattern:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(String.valueOf(file)));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-h][1-8]-[a-h][1-8][BQNRbqnr]?");
        List<String> filteredLines = lines.stream().filter(pattern.asPredicate()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if I have input like this garbo1239%)@a2-a5, I want the garbo to be filtered out.

I came up with the following solution to this problem:
I iterate over my String list and use the replaceAll method to filter out the junk:

```
for(int i = 0; i < filteredLines.size(); i++){
            filteredLines.set(i, filteredLines.get(i).replaceAll("[^[a-h][1-8]-[a-h][1-8]][BQNRbqnr]?",""));
        }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't have the desired effect. Things like a2-a4d or h7-h614 are still not being "cleaned" and I couldn't really figure out why. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about the exact thing you are asking but if you want each of your string to follow the pattern, `a2-a4, d7-d8`, you can try trimming the length of the string to only 5 characters.   Or, you can get the index of the hyphen(which seems to an important part of your pattern) using `indexOf()` method and then retrieve the previous two and next two characters using `substring()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "garbo1239%)@a2-a5", "a2-a4d", "h7-h614" };
        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*?([a-h][1-8]-[a-h][1-8][BQNRbqnr]?).*", "$1"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a2-a5
a2-a4
h7-h6
```

**Explanation:** Replace the given string with group(1) which is represented by `$1` where group(1) contains the regex for the desired output and everything before or after it needs to be discarded.